# Inheriting class with a function, with static members

Tags: c++, oop, class, inheritance, static

I have a Bullet class that has a function draw(). It want to pass in a static member(object of a SDL_surface class) to this function but not sure how to do it correctly.
my classes :

```
class AllyBullet: public Bullet
{

        public:

        static SDL_Surface *sprite;
};

class EnemyBullet: public Bullet
{

    public:

        static SDL_Surface *sprite;
};

void Bullet::Draw(SDL_Surface *screen)
{
    DrawSprite(screen,sprite,posX,posY);
}
```

Bullet does not have a sprite member. How can i write it so that it will know its for the classes that inherit it?

Comment: i have many objects of bullets, but all of them share the same bitmap.

Comment: (Sorry, I misthought. Comment removed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the sprite virtual. Something like this:

```
struct Bullet
{
   virtual Sprite getSprite() const;
   void Draw(SDL_Surface * screen)
   {
      DrawSprite(screen, getSprite(), posX, posY);
   }
   // ...
};

struct  AllyBullet : public Bullet
{
   static Sprite s;
   virtual Sprite getSprite() const { return s; }
   // ... 
};
```

Comment: Our answers are very similar :-)  But your answer requires that the developer implement a function `Bullet::getSprite()`, but how do we do that? [Pure virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function#C.2B.2B_2) functions are the answer.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I would leave it up to the OP whether to provide a default, make the function pure-virtual, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Bullet should specify a get_sprite() method, which must be implemented by AllyBullet and EnemyBullet:

```
class Bullet {
   virtual SDL_Surface * get_sprite() = 0;
}
```

which would be implemented as follows

```
   SDL_Surface * EnemyBullet :: get_sprite() { return sprite; }
   SDL_Surface * AllyBullet :: get_sprite() { return sprite; }
```

Then you can do

```
DrawSprite(screen,get_sprite(),posX,posY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If Bullet is (or can be) abstract then you can have a pure virtual function:

```
struct Bullet
{
    SDL_Surface* get_sprite () = 0;
}
```

Then each inherited class implements this method. But if they all do the same work (and should all have a sprite) then sprite belongs to Bullet and could be accessed with the getter:

```
strut Bullet
{
    SDL_Surface* get_sprite () { return sprite; }
}
```